# Cannot create document using go driver for ArangoDB

Tags: go, arangodb

The following function is supposed to create a new user record in Users collection:

```
func arangodb() {
 conn, err := http.NewConnection(http.ConnectionConfig{
    Endpoints: []string{"http://root@localhost:8529"},
})
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

c, err := driver.NewClient(driver.ClientConfig{
    Connection: conn,
})
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

// Open "examples_books" database
db, err := c.Database(nil, "_system")
if err != nil {
   panic(err)
 }


// Open "Users" collection
col, err := db.Collection(nil, "Users")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

type User struct {
    name string
    age int
}

// Create document
user := User{
    name:   "Bob",
    age: 25,
}
meta, err := col.CreateDocument(nil, user)
  if err != nil {
     panic(err)
 }
  fmt.Printf("%+v", meta)
  fmt.Printf("Created document in collection '%s' in database '%s'\n", 
   col.Name(), db.Name())
  }
```

Executing the above function prints following message:

```
{Key:7018 ID:Users/7018 Rev:_Z9bZbdC---}Created document in collection 'Users' in database 
'_system'
```

However in the web interface, the collection does not show the object created. It does show the _id, _rev and _key values and shows following for the object:

```
object{0}
    (empty  object)
```

My environment:
macOS Cataline version 10.15.2
ArangoDB 3.6.1
Go version 1.13.6

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your use struct fields are not exported. Capitalize them.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out. It is working now.